# Android Studio can't create a new blank Android project

Tags: android, macos, project, android-studio

I downloaded and installed Android Studio for Mac. Then, I tried to create a new blank project: the following is the result I had at the end of the wizard, after clicking Finish:

[image]

It seems Android Studio can't create a regular project. 
Can you tell me why? What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I upgraded it to 0.2.13. `Goto Help->Check for Updates`. And now its working.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but it isn't the only issue with this IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in android-studio-bundle-130.737825, visit here https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml for more update information.

For mac user, please click Help-Check for updates. If it doesn't work, please find  Info.plist in your Android Studio.app. There will be a fragment as

```
<key>VMOptions</key> <string>
```

and put

```
-Didea.updates.url=http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml 
-Didea.patches.url=http://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/
```

in string.

Comment: Nothing to do. Also, very annoying, the fact that sometimes, for no apparent reason, the tabs DESIGN/TEXT disappear and you can't select the desired view. I found plenty of solutions to the problem but none solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it be checking the "Include kotlin support" on the first screen when creating the Android project.